# 10 million award, so how are we going to get our tees?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

Yay! Congratulations to all of us! How can we get the those tees assuming I'll be one of them? I don't see where I put my full address in SO, I don't think there is. Will you email us about our postal address and the tees will reach us even in remote places of the globe? Just asking by an excited contributor, please don't be mean.

Comment: And here I was more worried about the whole "50 men's and 50 women's" shirts thing and how they'll sort that out. I certainly want a shirt, but I don't want a men's style shirt. ;) But I suppose it's a tad more important knowing how they'll actually be able to send said shirt.

Comment: @Kendra Maybe they'll keep choosing winners, asking them their genders, and saying, "Sorry Trobbins! We still have 37 women's shirts to give away, we're all out of men's!"  _Mod wobbles off to the next victim_

Comment: lol @Trobbins. But hey, I'm a skinny person, so perhaps the women's shirts won't be obvious on me.

Comment: I'm a girl. Yay. More chances to get a shirt. At least there is now one advantage to be a girl in IT.

Comment: @Mymozaaa Equality in action!

Comment: @OllieFord: I'm sure it's deliberately ironic that this is a good example of inequality in action.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wouldn't be so cynical. I think if I were responsible for such matters, I would realise I had no way of actually putting a figure on the M:F ratio (not to mention those that would object to being included in either figure..) - and decide I would meet with least objection by simply dishing them out 50:50.

There are many kinds of 'fair'; T-shirts are trivial enough for it not to matter too much! :)

Comment: @OllieFord: I would pick 50 and _then_ ask those 50 people what shape shirt they wanted. So that the distribution of who gets t-shirts _has nothing to do with gender_.

Comment: A gender discussion about T-shirts, rly? Careers, general rights, sexuality, I'm ok with that. But a rant about T-shirts?! But for the sake of the argument I go with @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Just pick a winner and ask him/her about the shirt. I think the clothing industry is way ahead in gender questions: All shirts will cost the same... ;)

Comment: @Mischback: I guess the principle is important no matter what the specific situation. In fact I'd go so far as to say that it's even more important in little cases like this because it shows peoples' true colours :)

Answer (score 41):

When you pass 100,000 reputation (or when you are elected a moderator) you also get a t-shirt, and in the past some sites [rewarded their top users](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/775/bicycles-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) with similar things.

In all three cases, I was sent a Google doc with a form to fill out my name, address and t-shirt size. I'm assuming this will be the same thing.

Comment: You have 100k+ rep + you are a mod, do you have 2 shirts now :]?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, as I said, *both times* I filled out a form

Comment: He said *all three cases*. This guy has three goddamn t-shirts!

Comment: @Voldemort One of them is a bikes.se shirt.

Comment: Meagar, consider donating one to me :)

Comment: If it were 1 T-shirt per each 100,000 points then Jon Skeet would have 8!!!

Comment: @Frakcool [Jon Skeet got much better prizes](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/)

Comment: @meagar oh... wow! that's really a better prize than a T-shirt... anyway I want a T-shirt! I'll need to go back and answer some more questions then...

Comment: Eeeh? a t-shirt after passing 100k? will have to start answering again!

Comment: Well I would not call canada "remote" from the US. What about Europe, Asia, Africa, Oceania and Australia or maybe Antarctica ;)

Comment: Is there also any detailed chart with height or width of the t-shirts? I have experienced a great difference in European and American t-shirts (even if written the same size, the American ones are always bigger) in both women's and men's.

Comment: **If** you're going to get anything, they'll contact you. There is no point emailing anybody about it.

Comment: 100k for a t-shirt? They should definitely put that in the priviledge page!